Verify only non-null fields
I need to adapt a Mockito verify method to check if the first parameter is equal to the expected value, and the second parameter, being a complex object, may have some fields set to null. I want to verify only the fields that are not null, that have a value.
Is it possible to do that?
public void verifyProfileOnce(UserId userId, Profile profile) {
    verify(profileClientMockBean, atLeastOnce()).valid(eq(userId), argThat(capturedList -> capturedList.stream().filter(capturedProfile -> profile.equals(capturedProfile)).count() == 1));
}

The signature of the mocked method:
void valid(UserId userId, List<Profile> profile);

Call example:
profileMock.verifyProfileOnce(userId.toString(),builder().name(TEST).email("test@test").address("qwerty").comment("First test").build());

The Profile object has several instances, and in the test, I only want to verify some of them, those constructed with the builder. I want to verify if the method was called with the userId and with the fields of the Profile object that are defined.

You start your question with "verify fields that are not null" and end it with "I only want to verify the fields that were set in the builder". Which of the two is your actual question? Since you are already using argThat, you only need to change your condition to verify the fields of the builder.

The list of Profile objects received as an argument in the stub method may vary depending on where the call is made, so the fields to check may not be the same. I want the match to only be made with the fields that are filled in and to ignore the null ones

So basically Object.equals(expected, field) || field == null?

I recommend using a Captor instead.
You could do this by writing a more-extensive custom ArgumentMatcher as a class. It's what you're already doing as a lambda, but ArgumentMatcher implementations can be arbitrarily complex.
verify(profileClientMockBean, atLeastOnce()).valid(
    eq(userId),
    argThat(new IsValidProfileList(profile));

public class IsValidProfileList implements ArgumentMatcher<List<Profile>> {
  private final Profile profile;

  public IsValidProfileList(Profile profile) { this.profile = profile; }

  @Override public boolean matches(List<Profile> profileList) {
    /* Loop through fields in profile, ignoring null as needed. */
  }

  @Override public String toString() {
    return "object that matches " + profile.toString();
  }
}

However, there's a problem: You probably have a single call to valid and care about the object matching correctly. ArgumentMatchers work by comparing all the calls to the mocked method (valid), so in the possibly-frequent case that you correctly have a single call to valid but the object is wrong, you'll get an error message that your call to valid was missing with the given parameters but a different call to valid exists with other parameters. This might be tractable if your Profile POJO has a really great toString method, but otherwise it will be a pain.
If you use an ArgumentCaptor instead, you can retrieve the object in your test and do all sorts of postverification on it. You can also use the @Captor annotation to avoid the generics.
/** Verifies one call with one profile, and returns the profile for examination. */
public Profile verifyProfileOnce(UserId userId) {
  // You might need to suppress warnings or cast here. Edits welcome.
  ArgumentCaptor<List<Profile>> profileCaptor =
      ArgumentCaptor.<List<Profile>>forClass(List.class);
  verify(profileClientMockBean, atLeastOnce()).valid(
      eq(userId),                // Keep this as an explicit eq, since capture
      profileCaptor.capture());  // counts as an argument matcher.
  List<Profile> profileList = profileCaptor.getValue();
  assertEquals(1, profileList.size());
  return profileList.get(0);
}

@Test public void yourTest() {
  // ... test
  Profile profile = profileMock.verifyProfileOnce(userId.toString());
  assertEquals(TEST, profile.getName());
  assertEquals("test@test", profile.getEmail());
  assertEquals("qwerty", profile.getAddress());
  assertEquals("First test", profile.getComment());
}

Benefits:

Assertions are extremely clear within the test itself.
You can use assertion libraries or non-equals assertions in the test.
Failures happen on a specific line and field.
If you want you can aggregate failures using something like assertAll so failures of multiple assertions can still all be visible at once.

Of course, you can still express those assertions in a helper method, and you can still use assertAll or non-assertion libraries in that helper method. It's just the case that ArgumentMatcher can lead to less-obvious failure messages when you're more confident about the number of calls to match and less confident about the objects you're matching.

Thanks for the explanation! It's clearer to me now.
